# How can I automatically open all the links on a page with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with 10 links and want to open all of them once I click on a button.

I use the following code, which is not working for me.

```
<a id="some-id" href="SOShousin3.jpg">Click Here</a><br />
<a id="some-id" href="SOShousin3.jpg">Click Here</a><br />
<a id="some-id" href="SOShousin3.jpg">Click Here</a><br />
<a id="some-id" href="SOShousin3.jpg">Click Here</a><br /><br />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a').click(function() {
        // assign an event to a.onclick
        window.open($(this).attr('href') );
    });

    $('ButtonOne').click(function() {
        // when we press <button>, trigger a.onclick
        $('a').click();
    });
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="ButtonOne">Open Links</button>
```

Comment: Please state what "it's not working" means

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12443639/1250044

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#ButtonOne').click(function() {
    $('a').each(function() {
        window.open($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ag2H5/)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a really bad idea:)  But here is how you might do this:

```
$('#ButtonOne').click(function() {
  $('a').each(function(){
    window.open($(this).attr('href') );
  });
});
```

You should also remove the onclick attribute and replace it with `id="ButtonOne"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is completely wrong.  It should be..

```
<button type="button" id='buttonOne'>Open Links</button>​
```

```js
$('#buttonOne').click(function() {
    // when we press <button>, trigger a.onclick
    $('a').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your selector for button is wrong,em, you should pass an right selector and it's better to set an id for button,try this

```
<a id="some-id" href="SOShousin3.jpg">Click Here</a><br />
<a id="some-id" href="SOShousin3.jpg">Click Here</a><br />
<a id="some-id" href="SOShousin3.jpg">Click Here</a><br />
<a id="some-id" href="SOShousin3.jpg">Click Here</a><br /><br />

<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').click(function() {
// assign an event to a.onclick
window.open($(this).attr('href') );
});

$('#ButtonOne').click(function() {
// when we press <button>, trigger a.onclick
$('a').click();
});

</script>
<button type="button" id="ButtonOne">Open Links</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the selector wrong in your $('ButtonOne'). This is trying to select all  elements. If ButtonOne is an id, you can use $("#ButtonOne"), if it is a class you can use $("button.ButtonOne"). Otherwise, the other two responses have it right.